# Can drag underneath a MUI dialog backdrop - why doesn't the modal backdrop stop the event propagation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-grid-layout

Repro here: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-blackburn-nrgj0b?file=/src/App.js

Usually a MUI (Material-UI) Dialog stops mouse clicking happening on components behind the backdrop when a Dialog component is open.

However for some reason a `react-grid-layout` element is still draggable underneath a MUI dialog.

I can't for the life of me see why that is?

It is fixable by adding the class `.MuiDialog-root` to the `draggableCancel` property of the `<GridLayout` `react-grid-layout` component - but this feels like a workaround for a bug for some event propagation that I am not understanding.

I added an issue to the `react-grid-layout` github repo here: https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-grid-layout/issues/1800

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue (maybe intended) with React:

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11387

Comment: "It is a know issue" should be a comment instead of an answer post. Though for you, sadly, this applies: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead